# Dictionary in for loop not working as I expected to be

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to create a dictionary using a for loop. However, not sure why, the item in bx3 and box is about 200+ but when I display dicts, only 22 items are generated. Anyone can explain what I did wrong? I ensure the length of items is considered in the for loop before creating the dictionary but the results are odd. Any help will be appreciated!

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

import yfinance as yf
import pandas_ta as ta

char2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l',
               'm','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

rep2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
  
    
x=[4,9]

x2= list(dict.fromkeys(x))
lx=[]

for n1,v1 in enumerate(rep2):
    for j in x2:
        if v1==j:
            lx.append((char2[n1]).upper())

print(lx)
print('')

#read_asx_ticker

ASXLIST_FILE = 'https://www.asx.com.au/asx/research/ASXListedCompanies.csv'

df =pd.read_csv(ASXLIST_FILE,header=1)
codelist = df['ASX code'].values
codesector = df['GICS industry group'].values

dd=lx

box=[]
box2=[]
bx=[]
bx2=[]
bx3=[]
for i in range(0,len(codesector)):
    if 'Not' not in codesector[i]:
        if len(set(dd).intersection(codelist[i]))>2:
            box.append(codelist[i])
            bx2.append(codesector[i])
            
        elif len(set(dd).intersection(codelist[i]))==2:
            box2.append(codelist[i])
            bx3.append(codesector[i])
            bx.append(codelist[i]+'/'+codesector[i])


dicts={}

for i in range(0,len(bx3)):
    dicts[bx3[i]]= box2[i]
```

Comment: Most probably you have repeated elements in bx3. Print them out to console and check whether this is the problem you are having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you only have 22 unique values in bx3 List.

Specifically you have these values repeated:

```
'Consumer Services': 6,
 'Materials': 103,
 'Health Care Equipment & Services': 15,
 'Commercial & Professional Services': 8,
 'Capital Goods': 13,
 'Software & Services': 12,
 'Diversified Financials': 7,
 'Energy': 10,
 'Transportation': 1,
 'Utilities': 2,
 'Retailing': 5,
 'Real Estate': 5,
 'Technology Hardware & Equipment': 3,
 'Pharmaceuticals, Biotechnology & Life Sciences': 10,
 'Household & Personal Products': 1,
 'Food & Staples Retailing': 1,
 'Food, Beverage & Tobacco': 4,
 'Media & Entertainment': 6,
 'Consumer Durables & Apparel': 1,
 'Banks': 1,
 'Semiconductors & Semiconductor Equipment': 1,
 'Automobiles & Components': 2
```